# How to create multiple temp views in spark using multiple data frame

Tags: pyspark

I have 10 data frame and i want to create multiple temp view so that I can perform sql operations on it using createOrReplaceTempView command in pyspark

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're after.

```
source_tables = [
    'sql.production.dbo.table1',
    'sql.production.dbo.table2',
    'sql.production.dbo.table3',
    'sql.production.dbo.table4',
    'sql.production.dbo.table5',
    'sql.production.dbo.table6',
    'sql.production.dbo.table7',
    'sql.production.dbo.table8',
    'sql.production.dbo.table9',
    'sql.production.dbo.table10'    
]

for source_table in source_tables:
 
    try:
        view_name = source_table.replace('.', '_')
        # Lowercase all column names
        df = df.toDF(*[c.lower() for c in df.columns])
        df.createOrReplaceTempView(view_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```